# SMBus Address and BaudRate

Tags: pic, i2c, serial, smbus

Hello I need to communicate with some batteries ( BT-70791CK from BrenTronics). They use SMBus ver 1.1 for communication, but in datasheet of the batteries there is no information about the SMBus address they have or the baudrate... I asked them and they told me that this is the only document that they have. So I started to think that maybe I do not need to know SMBus addresses or baudrate for SMBus communication. My questions are

1) Can I still communicate with devices that use SMBus ver 1.1. without knowing their addresses or baudrates?

2) Are there any spesific baudrate or SMBus address for batteries or for SMBus ver1.1?

Thank you beforehand.

Comment: Also posted on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240946/smbus-address-and-baudrate

Comment: 1) You could discover the address by scanning through them, checking on what address you get an ACK. For baudrate use the standard 100kHz or 400kHz?

Comment: Yes but in that case I need to try 128 addresses. And for baudrate SMBus allows frequency between 10 and 100 kHz and tells it is okay as long as you are in this range. However, it kinda confuses me because it is synchronous protocol but wants me to act as it is asynchronous.

Comment: You didn't say why is trying 128 addresses a problem. What's asynchronous about it?

Comment: Well I do not have batteries with me atm, so I need to write the code beforehand and I am new to I2C and also to PIC. In case of any error I will not know if it is because of the address or anything else.

Comment: The problem of "I need to write a driver that works, and I can't test beforehand" is MUCH harder than your question, even if you have complete docs and a lot of expertise writing drivers.

Comment: I know really but in any case shouldn't a producer mention about the SMBus addresses for their products. Do all the users need to try all the possible addresses? Maybe we are missing something here.

Comment: Yeah... the data sheet should mention what the battery monitor is, or at least what the specs of the SMBus are. I'd probably shoot them an email or call them up. Edit: apparently you did? That's just weird. SMBus is basically just I2C on crack. They need to tell you what the address is.

Comment: Note that standard smart batteries have a standard address of 0001 011. You could start with that.